# Git not recognizing remote using php/exec but fine in bash

Tags: php, git, bash

I am using a VM (homestead/laravel) to try to create a templated repository.

However although it all seemingly works fine but when it gets to pushing it never seems to recognize the remote.

```
fatal: No such remote 'origin'

fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

The above are the 2 errors I typically get.

I have tried a few commands to set the remote.

`git remote add origin https:://url.git` - does not add the remote (checked git config)

`git remote set-url origin https:://url.git` - does not add the remote (checked git config)

`git config remote.origin.url https:://url.git` - sets url, but still does not work.

These are private repos, and I am using https with the user:pass to handle it since I cannot easily manage ssh keys with this setup (in other words I am forced to use HTTPS in this way).

After trying the commands through php I navigate to the directory in ssh and run the push. Works fine (if I use the third option above). I have used `exec` and https://github.com/kbjr/Git.php but both end up having the same issue.

Git version is: 2.7.2

PHP version is: 7.1.0

The only thought I have is that technically there is a git repo above the one generated. I am creating the repo in a temp folder in laravel and then generating the "template" before pushing it to a repo I create during the process (github api). Once its all done I delete it locally. However I don't see any errors that could be related to problems caused by "a repo under a repo"

Comment: can u exec `pwd` to confirm u r working on properly directory?

Comment: if u r working on the properly directory, u should check ur repository permissions and if your run user have permissions to run it..

Comment: @gwdp I had thought that as well. I had provided full paths for all commands, also it is generating the git repo (git init) properly and it is doing it all from the same .sh file (getting executed from exec). For your second comment, the user does have permissions to the repo (pushing in ssh with the same remote works, but fails in php).

Comment: what `echo shell_exec("cd /var/www/git-repo && /full/path/to/bin/git pull 2>&1");` will output?

Comment: `.sh` but "Git.php" uses them individually as well though it uses `proc_open`

Comment: @gwdp The command you listed outputs `fatal: Couldn't find remote ref HEAD`

Comment: something seems wrong with your repo, or maybe (but very rare) on your git binary.. Try to debug it, first run the command I sent on separated .php file and execute.. try another repo and forward..

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

Ends up if you create a repo using the github API it does not actually create the repository before giving back the success response. So you need to force the script to wait before the push. In this case forcing it to wait 5 seconds (`sleep(5);`) seems to have resolved it.